# Flutter WebView: how to implement google translate inside content of a webview

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, webview

I would like to use the google translate tool to automatically translate the content of a webview, I haven't found any information about it for flutter. I only want to show in the `PopupMenuButton` of navigation an option of type "translate this page". I would appreciate some guidance.

This is what I have:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(nameCourse.toString()),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            PopupMenuButton<String>(
              onSelected: handleClick,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                return {
                  'Translate this page',
                  'Compartir mediante...',
                  'Abrir en Chrome',
                  'Copiar Enlace'
                }.map((String choice) {
                  return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                    value: choice,
                    child: Text(choice),
                  );
                }).toList();
              },
            ),
          ]),
      body: WebView(
        userAgent: "random",
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        initialUrl: urlCourse.toString(),
      ),
    );
  }

  void handleClick(String value) {
    switch (value) {
      case 'Copiar Enlace':
        copiarEnlace();
        break;
      case 'Translate thi page':
        //translate()
        break;
      case 'Abrir en Chrome':
        openUrl();
        break;
      case 'Compartir mediante...':
        compartirUrl();
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you find any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Not yet, for now this is not posible...
at least not with flutter

Comment: Okay, thank you. But if you find any solution please update here.

Comment: @CarlosPeñaranda Did you solve the problem? If yes, can you leave your answer please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview

It uses a chrome browser to show the web view and inside the web view, it has a 'Translate' option.

Comment: I can't find the Translate option.

Comment: This option appears in Chrome in-app browser's options after compiling the app. It's not method.